# Unassigned and recovering shards after heavy updating

Tags: elasticsearch

Shard won't recover after heavy updating. Anything I can do?

Is it a matter of waiting for the shard to recover? I see this over and over on the affected node, which happens to be the master:

```
[IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[global][2] failed to recover shard]; nested:
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [6]]; ]]
[2014-06-06 12:32:43,249][WARN ][indices.cluster] [Centurion] [global][5] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [global][5] failed to recover shard
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:241)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: No version type match [51]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType.fromValue(VersionType.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Index.readFrom(Translog.java:506)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogStreams.readTranslogOperation(TranslogStreams.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:218)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you check if the disk space on that box is full ?

Comment: I had a similar problem and needed to restart all the instances (this solved the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from `org.elasticsearch.index.translog` in the stack trace, this feels like a corrupted transaction log, which could have happened if the process crashed while trying to flush its updates out to disk. I've seen similar occasionally while hosting Elasticsearch over at [Bonsai.io](https://bonsai.io/).

If you remove the contents of the index translog directory, you should be able to proceed past that error and continue with shard recovery, though you'll need to reindex any documents that were updated around the time of the crash.

To avoid this in the future, you'll want to benchmark and tune your update process.

It's best to use the Bulk API instead of single-object updates, for more efficient memory management and less time and effort spent on GC. For update-heavy workloads, you'll also want to experiment with the number of primary shards. I'd recommend testing one primary shard per node, or one primary shard per CPU core per node.